# Filter for JSON File with jq (bash)

Tags: json

I have the following .json text:

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "data": {
    "0": {
      "orderid": "40007600",
      "price": "9.99",
      "listingname": "iPhone 8",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51b5iaLTjgL.jpg"
    },
    "1": {
      "orderid": "40007598",
      "price": "9.99",
      "listingname": "iPhone 8 Plus",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CVLqsSNkL.jpg"
    },
    "4": {
      "orderid": "40007595",
      "price": "9.39",
      "listingname": "Nadelflaschen",
      "smallphoto": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL._SL160_.jpg",
      "photo": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OHDP2rAeL.jpg"
    },
  }
```

I want a jq script that outputs:

```
"9.99" "iPhone 8"

"9.99" "iPhone 8 Plus"

"9.39" "Nadelflaschen"
```

in a .txt file.

So .data[] from "price" and "listingname".

I tried

> jq '.data[] | .price' '.data[] | .listingname'
>
> jq -M '..| .price?//empty' && '.. | .listingname?//empty'

None of both work.. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is the following:

```
jq '.data[] | .price, .listingname' data.json
```

That returns:

```
"9.99"
"iPhone 8"
"9.99"
"iPhone 8 Plus"
"9.39"
"Nadelflaschen"
```

> Comma: , If two filters are separated by a comma, then the same input
>   will be fed into both and the two filters’ output value streams will
>   be concatenated in order: first, all of the outputs produced by the
>   left expression, and then all of the outputs produced by the right.
>   For instance, filter .foo, .bar, produces both the “foo” fields and
>   “bar” fields as separate outputs.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters